# Are tomatoes worth rinsing off if you boil them soon after?

Tags: cleaning, tomatoes, produce

Have a large set of tomatoes to make some pasta sauce. To soften them for the food mill I boil them. My question is whether it's worth rinsing if they're eventaully gonna get boiled anyway?

Comment: You know the skins comes off very easily if you boil for just 30 seconds. That can give yo a smoother sauce. -No skin, nothing to rinse.

Comment: Were these store bought, or picked out of your garden? Store bought tomatoes are more likely to have pesticides and such. This could make a huge difference in handling recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Boiling can take care of any bacterial contaminants.

But boiled dirt still tastes like dirt. And boiled pesticides are probably still not good for you.

Answer (score 1):

I always rinse off vegetables before using them , even when blanching them.

In the case of tomatoes, I rinse them off, or more precisely, I give them a water bath and brush off dirt and cut away bad parts before blanching them.

Is it worth it? probably not; but I am more certain they are clean.

Answer (score 1):

Washing the dirt or store bought tomatoes is a must. When blanching them they won't have contaminants being absorbed.